# Flexed element inside a <core-header-panel> that is also flexed

Tags: polymer

Here's the code: http://jsbin.com/dusuda/12/edit

I'm using a core-header-panel element, and from what I've noticed it doesn't render unless it's set to flex. There're 3 elements inside core-header-panel, and what I want to achieve is having the middle element take up all the extra space by having it flexed as well. The ultimate goal here is to have a sticky footer at the bottom.

From sample code I've seen several uses of nested flexes so I thought it would be fine, but for some reason it's not working for me. I tried to flex the div with the yellow background but it's still just adopting the height of its contents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Core-header-panel` has two content insertion points (one for the header and one for the main content).
In your JSbin you added 3 divs (header, main and footer).
Futhermore the header has to be either a `core-toolbar` or a div with a `core-header` class and the main content insertion point has position `relative`.

Check the [official docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/layout-elements.html) on layout elements for more infos.

To solve your specific issue, I reduced the 3 divs to only 2 and used the `fit` attribute for the main + footer content.

See my JSBin: 
http://jsbin.com/fawof/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks Umit. This does explain a lot about core-header-panel requiring two insertion points, I just learned about that. I did indeed use a core-header class, but my actual code is a lot longer than what I provided in my jsbin since I tried to isolate the problem and removed all my custom elements and content. The problem seems to really be the fact that my core-header-panel had 3 children.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Put a large div inside the main part, so that it overflows vertically, and the footer gets messed up.